# WebApi project and MVC project in the same solution is the best practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm very confused with this scenario: in my new job there is an ASP.NET MVC App and a WebApi App in the same solution, the MVC' controller consumes the webApi controller and this sends JSON formatted data to the MVC' controller.

the app only works for the internet' users and in my opinion is so much work to do, so I exposed this to my boss and while talking he yelled at me: "no more ideas, this is the best way to work" and now I wonder to myself: is that true? why not create only a WebApi project to be self-hosted and create HTML pages to show the data?

so, could you please tell me if to have two projects in the same solution is the best practice? I still say no.

Comment: I don't necessarily see a problem with that. An API should be designed to be consumable by any client that speaks HTTP. You don't want all your MVC views to be along side the API if other clients use it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto a common services layer? I think that's what I was saying.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto certainly not. HTTP will never catch on.

Comment: 1. `if to have two projects in the same solution is the best practice` <= I see no problem here. 2. It is unclear how the MVC and Web API app communicate. Does the MVC app use a client side (ie. javascript) framework to make asynchronous calls to the Web API site? Or does the MVC backend code make web calls to the Web API site (with HttpClient for example)? Or is there a common service layer that both the MVC project and the Web API project call into and there is no cross site communication? The answer to this will determine if there is a "better" design/architecture that *could* be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering your question directly, I'd like to take a little detour. The key part here is this:

> I'm very confused with this scenario: **in my new job** there is an ASP.NET MVC App and a WebApi App in the same solution, the MVC' controller consumes the webApi controller and this sends JSON formatted data to the MVC' controller.

Whenever we join a new company, we view the architecture at that instant in time. We haven't seen the journey the software has taken in order to see *why* it's been built the way it has. If you're new, it can be hard to know the direction the architecture is taking.

That said, there is something to be careful of here:

> and while talking **he yelled** at me: "no more ideas, this is the best way to work"

New job or not, this isn't a productive way to build a relationship. If you're in a company whose culture isn't that open, people won't be used to being challenged/questioned about decisions made in the direction the software is taking. It will take you time, and a lot of energy, to build trust and earn some respect for people to start listening to you. It shouldn't be that way -  people should be open, and easy to talk to for things like this - but it's not always the case, so you need to keep that in mind when discussing your ideas.

With the above in mind, let's answer your question: is this architectural style right or wrong? The problem is, it totally depends on the journey the architecture has taken, and how it's evolving. Do I personally think the API should be separate? Yes! APIs are supposed to be scalable, without having to scale up/out the monolithic lump that is the rest of the application, but for all any of us knows, your employer might gradually be working towards that. In particular, it sounds like they may be trying to utilise microservice architecture, but again, whether that's appropriate for them, or whether it's being built correctly, is impossible for us to tell.

Comment: thanks, so it is better to have one solution for webApi and another one for the MVC project in order to manage scalability?

Comment: @PabloMayora It depends on the setup. You can still have the API and the MVC project in the same solution, and have them deployed to different environments (e.g. two different app services in Azure), which can be scaled independently. It also depends on how much logic needs to be shared between them. If you have monolithic architecture, in which all of the business logic lives in one solution, keeping the API in the same solution makes sense.

Comment: @PabloMayora That said, if your core business logic can be shared in a more distributed way, it can make it easier to maintain, and deploying things separately is somewhat easier as the generated artefacts are smaller. The different styles have different challenges. As above, determining if there is a better way to approach the architecture depends on many different questions. (See Igor's comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping more than one related projects in one solution is not a bad idea, at least for debugging purpose. Just you have to make sure, they don't use the common configuration file while running, or, if they do keep them divided, so that whenever you want, you can separate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In programming there not good and bad ideas exactly, this always depending of the Goal or objective, there are a lot of reasons of why that structure, (security, code separation, etc...), your boss is the only can answer you, but if he don´t want to talk about that, you can not decide if it is a bad implementation, not only for the reasons that i say, also because the company can have a planned to use that structure in the future